# SKEmitterNode not showing particle

Tags: xcode, swift, skemitternode

I wonder what's wrong with my code, it doesnt show the particles correctly.

[image]

and here's the expected particle

[image]

implementation

physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

```
    self.scene?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    self.scene?.size = CGSize(width: 640, height: 1136)

    self.addChild(SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "MagicParticle")!)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to safely unwrap the particle file first, just to make sure it cannot be nil

```
 if let particle = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "MagicParticle") {
    particle.position = ...
    addChild(particle)
 }
```

Its strange thats its not working, looking at your pictures it seems like you do not have a typo. 
Did you change the default spark.png in the particle effect?
Try cleaning your project or maybe delete the effect and create it again if it still doesn't work

As a side note, you can delete the 2 words

```
 scene?...
```

You are already in a SKScene, so self is the scene and therefore you can just say

```
 self.backgroundColor = ...
 self.size = ...
```

or better

```
 backgroundColor = ...
 size = ...
```

As a general good coding practice in swift try to only use "self" when the compiler forces you too. So say

```
addChild(...)
```

instead of

```
self.addChild(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should include also the file's extension, like this.

```
self.addChild(SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "MagicParticle.sks")!)
```